# "Conversion failed when converting" Is there a way to det. what row/ entry?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to determine what row/ date entry SQL is having trouble converting ? There are 300k date entries and I'm unsure which one my code is having a problem with. This code has worked in the past.

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string

Comment: You have tagged this question with both "mysql" and "sql-server". Which database are you in fact using?

Comment: I'm aware of two approaches.  The first is divide your dataset into smaller rowsets and attempt inserting them individually, working down until you find the problem row.  The second is to do some queries on the original data set and look for anomalies in the character string that you're trying to convert -- too long, characters that aren't usually related to dates, illegal patterns, etc.  It's usually a hassle.  Once you find the problem, you should try to add some safeguards to your process to keep that issue from occurring again.

Comment: Seems like someone has inserted an invalid date/timestamp value into the table... Use proper column data types and you wont have problems like this.

Comment: I can't see any code, i think you missed something.

Comment: Can you tag which version of sql server you are using?  Newer versions have some useful functions that may help.

Comment: So sorry, I accidentally added both. It is SQL MGMT studio. Unfortanly the software allows manual data entry for one filed. This is why we need to convert the dates, people enter them in differently.

Comment: @ANN SQL Server Management Studio is just the client application you are using to connect to SQL Server.  Do you know what version of SQL Server itself you are using?  If you are unsure you can run this in SSMS: `SELECT @@VERSION;`

Comment: Thank you ! I am new to sql . I figured out the issue :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use `TRY_CONVERT` to search for invalid date literals:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab_name
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(DATE, col_name) IS NULL
  AND col_name IS NOT NULL;
```

If necessary you could provide [date time style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=730ddb76937b58d12bc970191908f2a2)**

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the column was in a date format, using `ISDATE()`:

```
select myColumnDate
from myTable
where ISDATE(myColumnDate) = 0
```